# configuring dnsbl for exim4 (on debian)

Tags: debian, exim

Debian docu says i should do it this way:

```
CHECK_RCPT_DOMAIN_DNSBLS = zen.spamhaus.org/$sender_address_domain : dnsbl.sorbs.net/$sender_address_domain
```

but it does not work. my dialup ip is listed on dnsbl.sorbs.net but i can telnet to the mx and leave a message. not even a 'warning' header listed or something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to set the CHECK_RCPT_IP_DNSBL entry.  Something like
`CHECK_RCPT_IP_DNSBL = zen.spamhaus.org` should work.  I believe zen includes the sorbs list now.  The domain blocklist is for domains like `example.com` not IP addresses.

Comment: I knew that i was missing something obvious here :)
Thanks !